# Sequelize Query prepare issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have following raw query that I need to shift into Sequelize ORM query

> SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `user_posts` AS `user_posts` WHERE
> (`user_posts`.`source_id` = '621' AND `user_posts`.`source_type` =
> 'game' AND `user_posts`.`user_id` = 87 AND `user_posts`.`post_type_id`
> = 7 AND `user_posts`.`archive` = false) OR `user_posts`.`local_db_path` = 'xxx-xxx-xxx';

I have written following query in Sequelize ORM

```
let result = await Post.count({
      where:{
        local_db_path:local_db_path,
        [Op.or]:[
          {
            [Op.and]:[
              { source_id:inputs.source_id },
              { source_type:MAP_SOURCE_TYPE[inputs.source_type] },
              { user_id:user.id },
              { post_type_id:7 },
              { archive:false },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }      
    });
```

but this query add AND operation between local_db_path and braces condition but I need OR operator instead of AND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move `local_db_path` to Op.or cases:

```
let result = await Post.count({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      {
        [Op.and]: [
          { source_id: inputs.source_id },
          { source_type: MAP_SOURCE_TYPE[inputs.source_type] },
          { user_id: user.id },
          { post_type_id: 7 },
          { archive: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        local_db_path: 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Comment: In Sequelize, the conjunctions (unlike some of the other operators) all need to be parents of the objects/items they bind.  It makes for some gangling conditionals.  And, the default for the `where` attribute/clause is an implicit AND conjunction.